# PCI Compliance Apache Shiro fail

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, pci-dss

On a CentOS LAMP box, a PCI compliance scan is failing on:

```
Apache Shiro URI Path Security Traversal Information Disclosure http/80
```

As far as I can tell the server doesn't have Shiro installed, unless it's built in to Apache. I can't find any trace of it from searching the server for `shiro` and `shiro.ini`.

What could cause the scanner to believe Shiro is intalled and potentially vulnerable? Nothing is exposed in the `Server` header or the `ServerSignature`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the report didn't provide the information, request details on exactly what request and response triggered the detection.  It's hard to show that it's a false positive without being able to point out exactly what the flaw is in the scanner's detection logic - though it's pretty clear that it is a false positive, since Shiro isn't running.

Most often, this kind of false positive means that the response sent by the web server is not-quite-expected by the scanner - maybe your system is sending a response code of `200` or `30X` when the scanner thinks it should send a 404, or maybe something in the content of a custom error document made the scanner think that it had successfully obtained information from traversal.